# How do I upgrade Update Pipeline: Nodes and Processes to 2.15 in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot upgrade Pipeline: Nodes and Processes in Jenkins from 2.14 to 2.15.  I get the following errors in the stack trace:

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\ruby-runtime\WEB-INF\lib\classes.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\ruby-runtime'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these 2 options:

1. Restart Jenkins and see if that removes the lock. You can use ProcessExplorer to see what is locking it.
2. Disable the ruby-runtime plugin and then try upgrading the pipeline plugin.